# TClientDataset - is it possible to filter by unicode column name?

Tags: delphi, filter, delphi-2009, tclientdataset

I have a TClientDataset which could contain column names with non-ascii characters. It seems that I can not filter on such columns. Here is an example code:

```
uses
  DB, DBClient;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm34.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyDataset: TClientDataSet;
begin
  MyDataset := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  with MyDataset.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef do
  begin
    Name := 'PLACÓWKA';
    DataType := ftString;
  end;
  MyDataset.CreateDataSet;
  MyDataset.Open;
  MyDataset.Append;
  MyDataset.Fields[0].Value := 'Value_1';
  MyDataset.Post;
  MyDataset.Append;
  MyDataset.Fields[0].Value := 'Value_2';
  MyDataset.Post;
  MyDataset.Filter := 'PLACÓWKA LIKE ''%Value_1%''';
  MyDataset.Filtered := True; //Exception here: Field 'PLAC' not found
end;
```

After settings `MyDataset.Filtered := True` I am getting exception which says that Field 'PLAC' has not been found.

As far as I can tell the problem lies in method `TExprParser.SetExprParams` in `DBCommon` unit which could not properly parse the filter text.

Is there anything I can do with this besides renaming the column?

Comment: Try quoting the field name: `MyDataset.Filter := '"PLACÓWKA" LIKE ''%Value_1%''';`

Comment: I am getting error: Invalid filter expression character '"'

Comment: Then you're out of luck, I guess. Use ASCII-only field names, if possible.

Comment: Always avoid using unicode metadata. Just pure ASCII.

Comment: Quoted names should resolve, you just have to check what quote char the database expect, like braces in MSSQL  [PLACÓWKA].

Comment: Only for query you can create a View with ASCII only fields.

Comment: @CesarRomero your suggestion with [PLACÓWKA] worked. Create an answer from your comment so I will mark it as solution. Thanks

Comment: @Wodzu, Im glad it worked for you. Answer posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non ansi characters you should use quoted identifiers, each database have their default, in MSSQL it is braces **[ ]** like: **[ PLACÓWKA ]**.

If you are not  using MSSQL you should check your database docs for the appropriate quotes chars.